# How can Python access the X11 clipboard?

Tags: python, copy, clipboard, x11, paste

I want my Python script to be able to copy and paste to/from the clipboard via x11 (so that it will work on Linux). Can anyone point me to specific resources I can look at, or the concepts I would have to master?

Is this possible to do with the Python X library at http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net ?

Comment: note that, using `xlib`, or other solutions in answers below, will only copy/paste text ; whereas most applications nowadays copy/paste also image or other formats: for those, you may need `gtk` or `qt` libraries. Also the X11 clipboard is pasted using the middle mouse button, but not with ctrl-v , in most applications.

Answer (score 6):

**Tkinter-based solution** mentioned in [Cameron Laird's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902616/8277616):

```python
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
print(root.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD"))
```

Replace "CLIPBOARD" with "PRIMARY" to get `PRIMARY` selection instead.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16189232/8277616).

**python-xlib solution**, based on [PrintSelection()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992938/8277616) and [python-xlib/examples/get_selection.py](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/master/examples/get_selection.py)

```python
from Xlib import X, display as Xdisplay

def property2str(display, prop):
    if prop.property_type == display.get_atom("STRING"):
        return prop.value.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    elif prop.property_type == display.get_atom("UTF8_STRING"):
        return prop.value.decode('UTF-8')
    else:
        return "".join(str(c) for c in prop.value)

def get_selection(display, window, bufname, typename):
    bufid = display.get_atom(bufname)
    typeid = display.get_atom(typename)
    propid = display.get_atom('XSEL_DATA')
    incrid = display.get_atom('INCR')

    window.change_attributes(event_mask = X.PropertyChangeMask)
    window.convert_selection(bufid, typeid, propid, X.CurrentTime)
    while True:
        ev = display.next_event()
        if ev.type == X.SelectionNotify and ev.selection == bufid:
            break

    if ev.property == X.NONE:
        return None # request failed, e.g. owner can't convert to target format type
    else:
        prop = window.get_property(propid, X.AnyPropertyType, 0, 2**31-1, 1)

        if prop.property_type == incrid:
            result = ""
            while True:
                while True:
                    ev = display.next_event()
                    if ev.type == X.PropertyNotify and ev.atom == propid and ev.state == X.PropertyNewValue:
                        break

                prop = window.get_property(propid, X.AnyPropertyType, 0, 2**31-1, 1)
                if len(prop.value) == 0:
                    break

                result += property2str(display, prop)
            return result
        else:
            return property2str(display, prop)

display = Xdisplay.Display()
window = display.screen().root.create_window(0,0, 1,1, 0, X.CopyFromParent)
print( get_selection(display, window, "CLIPBOARD", "UTF8_STRING") or \
       get_selection(display, window, "CLIPBOARD", "STRING") )
```

Answer (score 3):

I favor a Tkinter-based solution over one which requires pygtk, simply because of the potential the latter has for installation challenges.  Given this, my recommendation to Alvin Smith is to read: [Cut & Paste Text Between Tkinter Widgets](https://web.archive.org/web/20091222020621/http://www.pythonpirates.com/alex/blog/2008/08/09/tkinter_clipboard_access)

You can use this code in a Tkinter event handler (from [python-list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-October/086052.html) via [Tkinter Clipboard access](https://web.archive.org/web/20091222020621/http://www.pythonpirates.com/alex/blog/2008/08/09/tkinter_clipboard_access)):

```
data =  event.widget.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD"))
```

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

[You can do this with pygtk](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkclipboard.html).  A clean solution but might be a bit overkill depending on your application.

Another method that gets some [google](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576887-shared-clipboard/)-[hits](http://www.answermysearches.com/python-how-to-copy-and-paste-to-the-clipboard-in-linux/286/) is to make a system call to [xsel](http://www.kfish.org/software/xsel/xsel.1x.html).

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 0):

## Using the `clipboard` module

First, install the [`clipboard`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipboard/) module using `pip3`:

```
$ sudo pip3 install clipboard
```

Using this cross-platform module (Linux, Mac, Windows) is pretty straightforward:

```
import clipboard
clipboard.copy('text')   # Copy to the clipboard.
text = clipboard.paste()   # Copy from the clipboard.
```

Comment: But that does not let you use the `PRIMARY` selection, does it?

Comment: according to the author of `clipboard` , this may be a better choice : `https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip`