# how to read data from clipboard and pass it as value to a variable in python?

Tags: python

how to read data from clipboard and pass it as value to a variable in python?

For example:

I will copy some data {eg: 200} by pressing ctrl+c or through rightclick. and pass it to a variable.

c = 200

..can any1 tel me how to do this?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: and which UI tool kit

Comment: windows 2008 server 64 bit

Comment: Getting text from the clipboard on ubuntu platform requires Tkinter.

Answer (score 11):

Just put [this](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) script in your path somewhere, say in your project folder, then;

```
import pyperclip # The name you have the file
x = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: link is a 404, presumably it went to this script http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/

Comment: On debian pyperclip is available as a package: as root run `apt-get install python-pyperclip` or `apt-get install python3-pyperclip` depending on your python version.

Answer (score 10):

To read from clipboard in your script with tkinter is this easy:

```
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# keep the window from showing
root.withdraw()

# read the clipboard
c = root.clipboard_get()
```

Comment: will throw an exception if the clipboard is not string-parseable. if files are in the clipboard, `c` will contain a `\n`-seperated list of paths. I have no idea about Python and would love to know if there is a proper way to find out if the clipboard contains pure text, no files, no blobs

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you _shouldn't_ put this code into a function. There have been cases of people wrapping this code in a `get_clipboard` function, which then creates a new `Tk` instance every time the function is called and ends up leaking memory because the window is never properly destroyed. So either 1) create a single (global?) `Tk` instance or 2) call `root.destroy()` to avoid leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for `Windows` OS!!

In C++ :
Use `GetData` by using `namespace` of `Systems.Windows`
See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx

And for python, you can use `gtk` or `Pygtk` libraries to do the same task! For example:

```
gtk.Clipboard()
```

Comment: i need for python not C++....

Comment: I have also mentioned for python as well :D

Comment: See this [link](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clipboard.html)

Comment: @Marco167 do you have a JavaScript example?