# Execute functions when clipboarg is modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need a little script which put the content of the clipboard in a variable and then "do things" (i.e. execute other functions with the variable as parameter). The script has to do it every time the clipboard is modified.

Right now I have:

```
def get_clipboard():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    try:
        return root.clipboard_get()
    except:
        return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cb = ""
    while True:
        cb_new = get_clipboard()
        if cb_new == cb or cb_new == "":
            continue
        cb = cb_new
        print(cb) # Here I will call other functions
        print("---------------------------------------------")
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

But I have an error after some time: `unable to realloc 28675 bytes`. I guess it is because of the `while` loop, but I don't know how to do it differently. I tried to use `mainloop`, but I don't understand how it work and if it is what I need.

Comment: May I ask where you've copied that `get_clipboard` function from so I can give it a downvote? It leaks memory.

Comment: @Rawing, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16189232/6634373) one.

Comment: That's the one. And as I don't know tkinter at all, I didn't see the problem.

Comment: Every time `get_clipboard()` is called, you are creating a _new_ invisible window. You never destroy this window. It won't take long before you have hundreds or thousands of these invisible windows, each one taking up some memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_clipboard` function creates a tkinter window but never properly destroys it. Doing this in a loop, 10 times per second, accumulates memory until there isn't enough left to create another window and your script crashes.

Change the function to this:

```
def get_clipboard():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    try:
        return root.clipboard_get()
    except:
        return ""
    finally:
        root.destroy()
```

Comment: Arguably even better would be to create the root window once at the start of the program, instead of continually creating and destroying it.