# Access primary selection with Python

Tags: python, linux

Is there a way to copy to \ paste from Linux primary selection in Python?

I need to write a couple of scripts and one of them needs to use the text stored in the Linux primary selection, another one needs to put there some text.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902263/how-can-python-access-the-x11-clipboard) answer your question?

Comment: quick'n'dirty `subprocess.check_output('xsel -p', shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

[Klembord](https://pypi.org/project/klembord/) python package does that.