# How can I put text in the clipboard using pure Python in Gnu/Linux?

Tags: python, clipboard, x11, wayland

I have a Python TUI application and I want it to save the result of a user selection from the keyboard.

It's pretty easy to find a Windows and Mac API to copy something to the user clipboard programmatically, but how to do so in Linux from Python?

It needs to:

- work accross desktop environments: at least Gnome Shell and KDE.
- work on X11 and Wayland.
- work without installing a third party package from the Linux repo (such as `xclip`) since you can't `pip install xclip`. This means the pypi clipboard package is excluded since it relies on that.
- it works without loading a GUI widget that requires the user to select the content, since the copy may happen in the background or in a TUI. The text may not be selected with the mouse.
- it should not install GTK, QT, or other heavy dependency that wouldn't be used for anything else. Installing a pure python 3rd party package is ok.

`xclip` does it for XWindows, so there muse be an API for that. And `wl-clipboard` for Wayland allows it, so there must be some C lib I can call using `ctypes` maybe.

Comment: Can this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902263/how-can-python-access-the-x11-clipboard

Comment: No, unfortunatly, the answers either use the clipboard lib, which uses a third party packages under the hood, or a GUI context, and my application doesn't have a GUI. I'll update the answer with this last part. In Windows and Mac, it's fairly simple to do, but I assume I'll have to ctype my way toward it under linux with variants accross DE.

Comment: If you want to use X11 anyway, whether your application _displays_ a GUI is unimportant. If using only native Python code is important, perhaps edit the title to highlight this.

Comment: Ok, I've done so.